# How to compare two JSON objects in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have an json object and store it as initialData and after some changes in store the json object into another modifiedData. Now I am trying to compare two json object of initialData and modifiedData but i could not able to compare it.

Note: Here json object are dynamic value.

Sample code:

```
let jsonObjectVal = JSON(message.body)
let initialData = jsonObjectVal
```

In save action i have modifiedData object.

```
 let jsonObjectModVal = JSON(message.body)
 let modifiedData = jsonObjectModVal

 if initialFormDataJson == jsonObjectVal {
     print("json object are equal save handler")
   } else  {      
     print("json object are not equal save handler")
   }
```

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: you have to create a model class which can accept both json objects and compair all the component one by

Comment: Where is this JSON type coming from? And what does actually happen if you run your code?

Comment: @ShivamParmar In my case json are dynamic object.

Comment: @Sven Json type coming from the webview javascript userContentController postMessage.

Comment: Maybe you don’t directly need an answer to this question but instead you should learn how to use `Codable` when working with json in swift

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare two completely arbitrary JSON objects (e.g. for unit testing), I'd suggest using the [GenericJSON](https://github.com/iwill/generic-json-swift) library. Add it to your project and/or Package.swift, and then (borrowing from @lazarevzubov's answer):

```
import GenericJSON

// Assume `YourObject` is `Encodable`
let testObject = YourObject(field1: "Some string", field2: 1, field3: ["Some string": 2])

let expectedData = """
{
   "field1":"Some string",
   "field2":1,
   "field3":{
      "Some string":2
   }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let expectedJSON = try? JSON(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: expectedData))
let actualJSON = try? JSON(encodable: testObject)

XCTAssertEqual(actualJSON, expectedJSON, "JSON should be equal")
```

A nice bonus is that you don't need to add any otherwise unnecessary `Decodable` or `Equatable` conformance to your model objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with a random data structure on how exactly you can do it:

```swift
import Foundation

final class YourObject: Decodable, Equatable {

    var field1: String
    var field2: Int
    var field3: [String : Double]

    static func == (lhs: YourObject, rhs: YourObject) -> Bool {
        lhs.field1 == rhs.field1
            && lhs.field2 == rhs.field2
            && lhs.field3 == rhs.field3
    }

}

let firstJSONString = """
{
   "field1":"Some string",
   "field2":1,
   "field3":{
      "Some string":2
   }
}
"""
let firstJSONData = firstJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!
let firstObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourObject.self, from: firstJSONData)

let secondJSONString = """
{
   "field1":"Some string",
   "field2":1,
   "field3":{
      "Some string":2
   }
}
""" // Same.
let secondJSONData = secondJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!
let secondObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourObject.self, from: secondJSONData)

let thirdJSONString = """
{
   "field1":"Some other string",
   "field2":2,
   "field3":{
      "Some string":3
   }
}
""" // Differs.
let thirdJSONData = thirdJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!
let thirdObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourObject.self, from: thirdJSONData)

print(firstObject == secondObject) // true
print(firstObject == thirdObject) // false
```

**Note:** You mentioned that the object should be dynamic, that's why it's a `class`. If you needed a value object, you would be able to use `struct` and avoid manual implementation of the `==`operator.

It's just a start of course. Having a specific JSON structure in your hands you can always search for more complicated examples, internet swarms with them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSObject class or struct from the JSON and compare all the properties to check for equality and return true/false accordingly.
Equatable protocol will come in handy here.

```
class A: Equatable {
    func equalTo(rhs: A) -> Bool {
        // whatever equality means for two As
    }
}

func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.equalTo(rhs)
}
```

Comment: how to implement this on my code?

Comment: Follow this tutorial for creating models. [JSON-Model](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-work-with-json-in-swift-83cd93a837e). And then use Equatable to compare your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare static mock json data and the real web API data like below:

```
func test_with_teams_successful_response_response_is_valid() async throws {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FooStaticData", ofType: "json"),
                  let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path) else {
                XCTFail("Failed to get the static foo file")
                return
            }
            MockURLSessionProtocol.loadingHandler = {
                let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: self.fooUrl,
                                               statusCode: 200,
                                               httpVersion: nil,
                                               headerFields: nil)
                return (response!, data)
            }
            
            let res = try await NetworkingManager.shared.request(session: session,
                                                                 .foo,
                                                                 type: FooModel.self)
            
            let staticJSON = try StaticJSONMapper.decode(file: "TeamsStaticData", type: FooModel.self)
            
            assertTeamsModelEqual(res, staticJSON)
            XCTAssertEqual(res, staticJSON, "The returned response should be decoded properly")
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

For Compare 2 objects use **===** operator

for eg.

```
let jsonObjectModVal = JSON(message.body)
 let modifiedData = jsonObjectModVal

 if initialFormDataJson === jsonObjectVal {
     print("json object are equal save handler")
   } else  {      
     print("json object are not equal save handler")
   }
```

Comment: Tried this not working

Comment: it shows error. Argument type 'JSON' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type